# how to understand this recursion in SML?

Tags: recursion, sml

why does hd dates become the oldest one? I just cannot figure out the process

```
fun oldest(dates : (int * int * int) list) = 
    if null dates
    then NONE
    else
        let
            val d = oldest(tl dates)
        in
            if isSome d andalso is_older(valOf d, hd dates) 
            then d
            else SOME(hd dates) 
        end
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Think of what would happen with an empty list, a list with one element, a list with two elements, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is much easier to understand with a small helper function and case analysis by pattern matching.
(My advice is to get comfortable with patterns and case analysis, avoiding conditionals and selector functions. It's much easier to reason about one thing at a time than to remember a whole chain of logic and destructuring.)

Rewriting your code in that manner might give this:

```
fun oldest_of (d, d') = if is_older (d, d') then d else d'

fun oldest [] = NONE
  | oldest (d::ds) = case oldest ds of
                        NONE => SOME d
                      | SOME d' => SOME (oldest_of (d, d'))
```

That is,

- If the list is empty, there is no oldest date
- Otherwise, find the oldest date in the input's tail;

  - If there isn't one, the input's first element must be the oldest
  - Otherwise, pick the oldest of that and the input's first element

Now it's (hopefully) obvious that the `NONE` case in the recursion can only occur if the tail, `ds`, is empty - that is, if the input has exactly one element.
Let's lift that out into its own case:

```
fun oldest [] = NONE
  | oldest [d] = SOME d
  | oldest (d::ds) =  SOME (oldest_of (d, valOf (oldest ds)))
```

This reads a lot like this definition of what the oldest date is:

- If there are no dates, there is no oldest date
- If there is only one date, that is the oldest
- If there are at least two dates, it is the oldest of the first date and the oldest one of the rest

which doesn't need much inductive thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by induction:

1. In the case of an empty list, `oldest` will return `NONE`.
2. If the list contains an element, we'll go into the `else` branch, `let`ting `d` be `NONE`, because `tl` of a list with one element returns an empty list. `isSome d` will be false, which is why we will return `SOME(hd dates)` — the only element, which is by definition the oldest.
3. Assuming the function works for the case of a list of *n-1* items, let's see what happens when the list has *n* items: We will go into the `else` branch and assign to `d` the oldest element from the tail of the list (which works, because it contains *n-1* items). Now there's two possible scenarios:

   a. `d` is older than the first element of the list. In that case, `d` will be returned, because both `isSome d` and `is_older(valOf d, hd dates)` will be true.

   b. `d` is not older than the first element of the list. We will therefore return `SOME(hd dates)` — the first element of the list.
4. We have shown that it works for *n* elements if it works for *n-1*, and we have shown that it works for n=0 and n=1 (technically we could have skipped step 2). It will therefore work for a list of any size.

Comment: Thanks for offer me an answer that so precise!!! I am learning induction recently, I know how to prove it in math but when I asked to do that in programming I found it is really difficult.